# Deserializing an ArrayList. no valid constructor

Tags: java, serialization, io, persistence, deserialization

This how I deserialize my arrayList which contains objects of identification

```
public void deserializeArrayList(){
    String path = "./qbank/IdentificationHARD.quiz";
    try{
          FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(path);
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
            ArrayList<Identification> list = (ArrayList<Identification>) in.readObject();
            System.out.println(list);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is how I serialize it

```
public void saveItemIdentification(ArrayList<Identification> identification,File file){
    try{
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(
                                      new FileOutputStream(file));
        out.writeObject(identification);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But when I deserialize it it gives me this errors

```
java.io.InvalidClassException: quizmaker.management.Identification; quizmaker.management.Identification; no valid constructor
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.checkDeserialize(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at quizmaker.management.Manage.deserializeArrayList(Manage.java:92)
```

This is line 92

```
ArrayList<Identification> list = (ArrayList<Identification>) in.readObject();
```

Why is this happening?

This is the  code of `Identification` Object.

```
 package quizmaker.management; 
 import java.io.Serializable;
 import quizmaker.Accounts.Rights.IAnswerable;

public class Identification extends Question implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2L;
    private String question;
    private String answer;

    public Identification(String q , String a){
        super(q,a);
    }

    public String toString(){
        return String.format("Question: %s\n Answer %s", getQuestion(),getAnswer());
    }
}
```

Comment: What about your `Identification` object?

Comment: can you put some code of your Identification class

Comment: @SumitSingh I updated it please check

Comment: Make a default constructor for `Identification`.

Comment: Why should add a default constructor??

Comment: But it returned me an empty items. even though I added values to those object I inserted.

Comment: is your Question  class implements Serializable..?\

Comment: @user962206 Either [`Question` needs a no-arg constructor e.g. `private Question() { }`](http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=251942), or you create one for `Identification`.

Comment: @SumitSingh I added Serializable to Question class. it is now showing its values! Now how did that Happen?

Comment: @user962206 I put the reason in Answer you can see that :)